# Angular EventEmitter not triggered in javascript plugin callback

Tags: angular

EventEmitter not detected when triggered from javascript plugin's callback.
The dummy code would look like.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
declare var $: any;
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: 'app/component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/component.css']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    @Output() onComposing: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    private curUser: any;
    private JSONObj: any = null;
    constructor(private router: Router, private zone: NgZone) {
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.JSONObj = {
            onGetConfirmation: ()=> {
                this.notifyStatus();
            }
        }
        //works fine if I put code here event detected
        /*setInterval(()=>{
            this.onComposing.emit({
                date: (new Date()).getTime(),
                user: 'Some data' + (new Date()).getTime()
            });
        },1000);*/
    }
    notifyStatus(){
        this.zone.run(() => {
            //reaching here but not detected
            this.onComposing.emit({
                date: (new Date()).getTime(),
                user: 'some data' + (new Date()).getTime()
            });
        });
    }
    //triggered from UI
    doSomething(user: any) {
        var pluginInstance = this.plugin.getInstance();//from some plugin
        pluginInstance.toDoSomething(this.JSONObj);
    }
}
```

It is working fine if the EventEmitter triggered inside the setInterval block
 for testing purpose but not when triggered from javascript callback function

Comment: How does `notifyStatus()` get called?

Comment: @Brad Please find the flow<br>
1.doSomething called from UI say Click
2.pluginInstance.toDoSomething(this.JSONObj); is called.
3.plugin process something and on success called this.JSONObj.onGetConfirmation
4.notifyStatus is triggered from this.JSONObj.onGetConfirmation

Comment: Your code doesn't indicate how the `pluginInstance` actually uses `this.JSONObj`.  Can you post that part of your code.

Comment: toDoSomething method registed JSONObj into the plugin and inside plugin system received web socket notification plugin parsed that notification continuously and on notification trigger onGetConfirmation of this.JSONObj and onGetConfirmation called notifyStatus method.

Comment: Would be great if you could provide a plunker